# unable to build cordova project after adding Geofence plugin

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-services, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I m new to visual studio 2017 and i am trying to create cordova project from that. since I created sample cordova project successfully(without any plugin).
secondly I created one more cordova app by adding the geofence plugin from https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence.git It is throwing error.

Error:

> ```
> 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : FAILURE: Build failed with an 
> exception.
> 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:
> 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : A problem occurred configuring root 
> project 'android'.
>
> BUILD FAILED
> ```
>
> Total time: 6.5 secs

```
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > Could not resolve all dependencies for 
configuration ':_debugCompile'.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  > Could not find any matches for 
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+ as no versions of 
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location are available.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  Searched in the following locations:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services- 
location/maven-metadata.xml
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services- 
location/
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services- 
location/maven-metadata.xml
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error
file:/C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/AndroidSDK/25/extras
/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven- 
metadata.xml
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  
file:/C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/AndroidSDK/25/extras
/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  Required by:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  :android:unspecified
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * Try:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Run with --stacktrace option to get the 
stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c 
"C:\Users\kumar\source\repos\geoApp\GeoApp\platforms\android\gradlew.bat 
cdvBuildDebug -b 
C:\Users\kumar\source\repos\geoApp\GeoApp\platforms\android\build.gradle - 
Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 
1 Error output:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:
 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : A problem occurred configuring root 
 project 'android'.
 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > Could not resolve all dependencies for 
 configuration ':_debugCompile'.
 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  > Could not find any matches for 
 com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+ as no versions of 
 com.google.android.gms:play-services-location are available.
 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  Searched in the following locations:
 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  
 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services- 
 location/maven-metadata.xml
 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  
 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services- 
 location/
 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  
 https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services- 
 location/maven-metadata.xml
 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  
 https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/
 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :              
 file:/C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/AndroidSDK/25/extras/android
  /m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven- 
   metadata.xml
   1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  
   file:/C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/AndroidSDK/25/extras/android
  /m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/
 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  Required by:
 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  :android:unspecified
 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * Try:
 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Run with --stacktrace option to get the 
 stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
 1>Done building project "GeoApp.jsproj" -- FAILED.
 ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

and also I have installed following packages in sdk manager(android studio)

Google Play Services

Android Support Repository

Google Repository

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks